# Fullcalendar problem when adding Bootstrap and custom event indicator

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I'm migrating an old project based on Fullcalendar 1.x + Bootstrap 3 to the latest version of Fullcalendar + Bootstrap 5.

In order to display holidays, instead of using background events we like to add a little icon next to the date and use a tooltip to indicate what the holiday is about, as can be seen in the screenshot.

[image: background event as tooltip]

This works fine **without** Bootstrap, as can be seen [here](https://codepen.io/Pablo-Bendersky/pen/OJrdbEo)

However, as soon as I add Bootstrap's CSS as can be seen [here](https://codepen.io/Pablo-Bendersky/pen/oNJVoRP) the tooltip breaks.

I've tried it with Bootstrap's native tooltips as well, and its the same... It appears to be a conflict between Bootstrap's CSS and Fullcalendar's, but I cannot find it.

The JS I use to render the event tooltips is this one:

```js
// import bootstrap5Plugin from '@fullcalendar/bootstrap5';

var DateTime = luxon.DateTime;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    timeZone: 'local',
    // plugins: [
    //   bootstrap5Plugin,
    // ],
    headerToolbar: {
      start: 'prev,today,next',
      center: 'title',
      end: 'dayGridMonth,dayGridWeek,dayGridDay'
    },
    // themeSystem: 'bootstrap5',
    eventDidMount: function(info) {
      const element = info.el;
      const event = info.event;

      const date = DateTime.fromJSDate(event.start).toFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
      const cell = document.querySelector(`td[data-date="${date}"] .fc-daygrid-day-top`);
      if (cell != null) {
        var ta = document.createElement('a');
        ta.setAttribute('data-bs-toggle', 'tooltip');
        ta.setAttribute('data-bs-title', event.title);
        ta.setAttribute('data-bs-placement', 'top');
        ta.setAttribute('href', 'https://google.com');
        ta.innerText = 'xxx';
        cell.appendChild(ta);
        
        var tooltipDay = new Tooltip(ta, {
          title: info.event.extendedProps.description,
          placement: 'top',
          trigger: 'hover',
          container: 'body'
        });
      }
      
      var tooltip = new Tooltip(info.el, {
        title: info.event.extendedProps.description,
        placement: 'top',
        trigger: 'hover',
        container: 'body'
      });
    },

    events: [{
      "title": "All Day Event",
      "description": 'description for All Day Event',
      "start": "2023-10-04"
    }],
    editable: false,
    selectable: false
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```